# How to draw text without window

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to display text on the screen, on top of everything, not clickable, without having any window. The idea is to be able to show notifications. I'm somewhat close from what I want, but a really weird problem just showed. This is the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>  

int main(void){

    HDC hdc = ::GetDC(0);
    RECT rect;
    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 255));
    SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    auto hFont = CreateFont(40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, L"Verdana");
    auto hTmp = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
    rect.left = 40;
    rect.top = 10;

    while (true){
        DrawText(hdc, L"THIS IS A TEXT", -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_NOCLIP);
        Sleep(1);
    }
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, hTmp));
    ::ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
    return 0;

}
```

and this is what happens when I change the text settings from `red` to `blue` and size `80` to `40`:

[image: buggz]

For some reason I can still see the old text, after rerunning the program, which tells me that I misunderstood something. Is there a better, cleaner way to do this?

EDIT: I checked windows notifications and that's NOT a solution. Imagine you are playing a full screen game, and want to know if an email arrives. Another essential thing is that it cannot be clickable, so that clicks by mistake don't minimize your game. How annoying is that skype popup that minimizes your application when you get a call?

Comment: You are drawing on main device context.

Comment: @mudasobwa could you please clarify your comment? What does that mean?

Comment: "The idea is to be able to show notifications." Custom notification systems are awful and it's better to just not get notified of anything. When your OS supports a built-in, system notification mechanism (as Windows 10 will) just use that.

Comment: @bames53 Is it possible to use windows 7 features to display notifications without getting in the way? I checked that possibility and found nothing. I just want a small rectangle of text saying: you have a new mail or something like that. In a way that doesn't disturb what you are doing.

Comment: I've added the winapi tag, but I'm not convinced this is a C++ question.

Comment: Take a look at the provided WinAPI functionality under [Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You say you want to not disturb the user, and this is the way to do it.

Comment: why don't you want to have a window?

Comment: @wonkorealtime I don't want anything that a window provides.

Comment: The concept seems flawed to me - you want a notification that the user _must_ see, but without it getting in the way. If you really want to go this route, then I suggest looking at how splashscreens are implemented, which in general is a borderless window with a timeout prior to closing itself.

Comment: @icabod I don't see what the problem is. You probably have the same thing in your phone already. At least I do. When I get a message, a small line of text appears at the top of the screen no matter what, and it doesn't get in the way. I could have a window, but I don't want to minimize fullscreen apps if I click it by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have bypassed all of the windows/client controls and so the system has no idea that this area needs to be cleared. You need to tell it manually, especially since you are not using the windows message notification mechanism.

Before drawing to it, you want to invalidate that part of the screen and tell windows to redraw it:

```
::InvalidateRect (0, &rect, false);   //  Redraw without erasing. If doesn't help, try true
::UpdateWindow (0);
while (true)...
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Just one more thing: is there a way to make this work over a fullscreen app?

Comment: If someone is using a fullscreen app then they don't want to see notifications. Don't get into a topmost competition.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up running into a lot of problems, while trying to make this work. If someone ends up visiting this page looking for an answer to the same problems I ran into, I hope you have an easier time than I had. This is the code that worked for me:

```
#include <Windows.h> 


INT WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    // Define and initialize variables
    HDC          hdc;
    HDC          hdcMem;
    HBITMAP      hbmMem;
    HANDLE       hOld;
    RECT rect;
    SIZE sz;
    int win_width = 0;
    int win_height = 0;
    int font_size = 20;
    int location_x = 40;
    int location_y = 40;
    int border = font_size / 4;
    int duration = 10000;           // In miliseconds. The notification will always stay up more time
    wchar_t* font_face = L"Consolas";
    wchar_t message[100];

    // Save command-line arguments to message; They are showed by the notification
    MultiByteToWideChar(0, 0,
        lpCmdLine,
        strlen(lpCmdLine),
        message,
        100
        );
    message[strlen(lpCmdLine)] = L'\0';


    // Acquire screen
    hdc = ::GetDC(0);

    //Create necessary font
    HFONT hFont = CreateFont(font_size, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, font_face);
    HFONT hTmp = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

    // Calculate size of the text
    GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, message, wcslen(message), &sz);
    win_width = sz.cx;
    win_height = sz.cy;
    rect = { 0, 0, sz.cx, sz.cx };

    // Create an off-screen DC for double-buffering
    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    hbmMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, win_width + 2 * border, win_height + 2 * border);

    // Configure off-screen DC
    SetBkMode(hdcMem, OPAQUE);
    SetTextColor(hdcMem, RGB(125, 125, 255));
    SetBkColor(hdcMem, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hFont);
    hOld = SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmMem);

    // Draw loop
    for (int i = 0; i < duration; i++)
    {
        // Draw into hdcMem
        DrawText(hdcMem, message, -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE);

        // Transfer the off-screen DC to the screen
        BitBlt(hdc, location_x, location_y, win_width + 2 * border, win_height + 2 * border, hdcMem, -5, -5, SRCCOPY);


        // Don't eat all the cpu!
        Sleep(1);
    }

    // Delete notification right after time expires
    ::InvalidateRect(0, &rect, false);
    ::UpdateWindow(0);

    // Free-up the off-screen DC
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hOld);
    DeleteObject(hbmMem);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);

    // Release created objects
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, hTmp));
    ::ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
    return 0;
}
```

It can still be improved, a lot. The only thing that appears is the rectangle with the notification.
The arguments that you pass to the program will be shown as a message. Everything related with `hdcMem` was implemented to avoid flickering. I can't yet change the background of the bigger rectangle.